# Using HEX editor and making 4 chars from 3 chars

Tags: c++, hex, patch-reversing, strings

I need to replace a single string in a bin. The actual string has 3 chars and the new one must have 4.If I use a hex editor this will make the exe useless.So is there any way to add bytes there to make it a 4 char string?

Comment: no unless you detour you cant mess with length

Comment: @blabb that is the only way?

Answer (score 2):

As Far As i Know there isn't another way 
assume you have a program like this

[image]

the hex for this function will look like this

```
0:000> db main l21
00111260  55 8b ec 6a 00 eb 04 74-68 69 00 68 67 12 11 00  U..j...thi.hg...
00111270  68 67 12 11 00 6a 00 ff-15 5c c1 14 00 33 c0 5d  hg...j...\...3.]
00111280  c3
```

and disassembling the function will yield this

```
0:000> uf main 
smallstr!main [e:\test\smallstr\smallstr.cpp @ 2]:
    2 00111260 55              push    ebp
    2 00111261 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
    5 00111263 6a00            push    0
    6 00111265 eb04            jmp     smallstr!main+0xb (0011126b)  Branch

smallstr!main+0xb [e:\test\smallstr\smallstr.cpp @ 13]:
   13 0011126b 6867121100      push    offset smallstr!main+0x7 (00111267)
   14 00111270 6867121100      push    offset smallstr!main+0x7 (00111267)
   15 00111275 6a00            push    0
   16 00111277 ff155cc11400    call    dword ptr [smallstr!_imp__MessageBoxA (0014c15c)]
   18 0011127d 33c0            xor     eax,eax
   19 0011127f 5d              pop     ebp
   19 00111280 c3              ret
```

can you think of a way to alter the string 
**"thi"** to 
`"i know what i do don't you dare to interfere with me"`

the only way possible is recompile if you have source 
or detour the pointers to string

if you are detouring you have to take care of relocations too

```
00D71260 smallstr.main       /$  55            PUSH    EBP
00D71261                     |.  8BEC          MOV     EBP, ESP
00D71263                     |.  6A 00         PUSH    0
00D71265                     |.  EB 04         JMP     SHORT 00D7126B                ;  00D7126B
00D71267                     |.  74 68 69 00   ASCII   "thi",0
00D7126B                     |>  68 6712D700   PUSH    0D71267                       ; |Title = "thi"
00D71270                     |.  68 6712D700   PUSH    0D71267                       ; |Text = "thi"
00D71275                     |.  6A 00         PUSH    0                             ; |hOwner = NULL
00D71277                     |.  FF15 5CC1DA00 CALL    NEAR DWORD PTR DS:[DAC15C]    ; \MessageBoxA
00D7127D                     |.  33C0          XOR     EAX, EAX
00D7127F                     |.  5D            POP     EBP
00D71280                     \.  C3            RETN
```

Comment: I have the source but is updated and I need to use an old bin .I don't know much about RE but I try to use this and do my best .Thanks for help